# how to generate random value in each time I run the lua script

Tags: linux, lua, lua-scripting-library

I have written a lua script named **"lua_rand_gen"** which contains following code:

```
function random_number_func()
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    return (math.random(100000000,999999999))
end

print (random_number_func())
```

when I run the **lua_rand_gen** script in the terminal in loop , the above function is not generating randome values as shown :

```
for ((i=0;i<=5;i++)); do lua lua_rand_gen; done

717952767
717952767
717952767
717952767
717952767
717952767
```

I know this is because **os.time()** doesn't change till one second. So, how can I get Random number in lua if the time difference between running the lua script is less than 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Move `math.randomseed(os.time())` outside the function.

It seems to be a common misconception that you need to call `math.randomseed` before each time you call `math.random`. This is *wrong* and will defeat the randomness of `math.random`, especially if you use `os.time()` as seed, since the seeds will be the same for a whole second.

Comment: IMO, function name `randomseed(seed)` is not informative for beginners.  Probably, `startrandomsequence(sequenceid)` would be more clear?

Comment: "lua_rand_gen" is a script file each time i run the script it executes the function writen the lua_rand_gen file (which is mentioned above) and exits , and I am not getting random numbers if I the run the script within the time interval of 1 secound